# Build C# solution in TFS 2010 using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: tfsbuild

We have a team project in TFS 2010 and currently being built using VS 2010. I just upgraded my local copy to build successfully in VS 2012. Now I am not sure what I need to do to make the solution built in VS 2012 in our TFS 2010 server.

Obviously VS 2012 needs to be installed on the build machine. What else is needed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: nothing (not even the VS 2012). All you need is to take care of the VS solution itself.

I've not update the VS on the tfs build agent and until now haven't run into trouble. 
The update of my solution from VS2010 to VS2012 was the automatically suggested by the VS2012 wizard when opening an older VS solution.
The only issue that I had was related with the code analisys dlls absolute paths (point to the VS 2010 folders) on the .csprojs. To solve this I removed the callout to the dlls, but left the code analisys on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I installed VS2012 on the build agent and it worked. Whether VS2012 is needed or not I am not sure.